# Windows Performance Analyzer cannot load symbols

Tags: windows, xperf, windows-performance-analyzer

I open .etl(produced by xperf) file with WPA, I can see the information about Analysis:
[image]

I also want to see the process stack, and  I think I should load symbols first. But the Load Symbols in Trace is grayed out:
[image]

I want to ask how to load symbols to see the process stack?

WPA version: 10.0.19041.685(WinBuild.160101.0800)

OS version: Windows Server 2019 Datacenter

OS build: 17763.1637

Comment: did you stop the trace with -d **xperf -d NAME.etl**? This is important to include the symbol info

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: I haven`t solved the problem, because I cannot run` xperf `command, I only have the .etl file which does not have a problem.

Comment: if this trace is not captured correctly you can't fix it. Open the trace in [Perfview](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/releases/latest) and if you can't find [KernelTraceControl/DbgID_RSDS events](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/bcl/blob/master/Tools/ETW/traceEvent/SymbolEventParser.cs#L36) the ETL is useless.

Comment: because you haven't replied I wrote now an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to load debug symbols, it is required to have the PDB names + a GUID that is generated during linking.

This information is not included, so all ETW tools add `KernelTraceControl/DbgID_RSDS` [events to ETL files](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/bcl/blob/master/Tools/ETW/traceEvent/SymbolEventParser.cs#L36) at stop in a merge step. When using xperf, you have to call -d at stop (`xperf -d result.etl`).

To verify that the required event is included, open the ETL in [Perfview](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/releases/latest) in look in events:

[image]

If you can't find the events, the trace was not captured correctly and is useless.